# Как сделать ожидание цикла, чтобы потом выполнялся до конца

Tags: c#

Вот мой сам пример кода

```
    static void startConsole()
    {
        while (!(kaut = Decryptor(Console.ReadLine(), ' '))[0].Equals("exit"))
        {
            try
            {
                comands[kaut[0]].command.Start();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                try
                {
                    ToRead(kaut);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(kaut[0] + " - Ошибка прочтения команды");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Мне требуется чтобы цикл не продолжал работать пока работает 1 поток который запускается через массив

Описание класса:

```
public class Comand {
  public String name; 
  public Thread command; 
  public String help; 
  public Comand(String name, Thread command, String help) { 
    this.name = name; 
    this.command = command; 
    this.help = help; 
  } 
  public Comand(Thread command, String help) { 
    this.help = help; 
    this.command = command; 
  } 
}
```

Comment: Это новая мода код в картинку пихать?

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: опишите, что за объекты `comands` у Вас? Что за метод `Start()`

Comment: `public static Dictionary<String, Comand> comands = new Dictionary<string, Comand>();` это словарик в котором есть команды, а сам класс вот `public class Comand
    {
        public String name;
        public Thread command;
        public String help;

        public Comand(String name, Thread command, String help)
        {
            this.name = name;
            this.command = command;
            this.help = help;
        }
        public Comand(Thread command, String help)
        {
            this.help = help;
            this.command = command;
        }
    }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

думаю как-то так

```
comands[kaut[0]].command.Start();
while (!comands[kaut[0]].command.Join(1000)) { }
```

Ожидаем максимум секунду, если поток не завершился ждем еще секунду. и т.д. в теле цикла можно описать дополнительную логику если надо

или

```
comands[kaut[0]].command.Start();
comands[kaut[0]].command.Join();
```

для бесконечного ожидания

Методы: Блокирует вызывающий поток до завершения потока, представленного экземпляром, или истечения указанного времени, продолжая отправлять стандартные сообщения COM и SendMessage.

[Thread.Join()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/95hbf2ta(v=vs.110).aspx), [Thread.Join(Int32)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/6b1kkss0(v=vs.110).aspx), [Thread.Join(TimeSpan)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/23f7b1ct(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Спасибо что помог, я рад результату